# When is “maybe” used, versus “perhaps”?

Tags: word-difference

I don't know the difference between these words.

When is it correct to use “maybe” and when is it correct to use “perhaps”?

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Did you look these words up in a dictionary?

Comment: @WendiKidd I don't think it's gonna do him much good; the four dictionaries I consulted just xrefed the two.

Comment: Yes, I do, however I don't know in what place used it

Comment: You could start [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12875/maybe-versus-perhaps), where you'll also find [this page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv162.shtml) to explore.

Answer (score 4):

We can find the exact same quote in the Wiktionary entries for [both](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maybe) [words](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perhaps):

> Modifies a verb, indicating a lack of certainty.

So in terms of meaning, they're generally interchangeable.  One difference, pointed out by BobRodes, is that *perhaps* is more formal and polite, while *maybe* is less so.  But there's a good deal of overlap, so it's not unusual to see both terms used in the same passage.

---

Although it's rare, one difference is that *maybe* can be used informally as a noun.  Here's a definition from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/maybes):

> *n. Informal*
>   **1.** An uncertainty: *There are so many maybes involved in playing the stock market.*
>   **2.** An uncertain reply: *It's better to receive a fast and honest no than a drawn-out maybe.*

It's technically possible for *perhaps* to be turned into a noun the same way, but it's comparatively rare, perhaps because **perhapses* sounds so clunky.  When I searched [*The Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)*](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), I found 53 results for `maybes` and 0 results for `perhapses`.

---

Now that we've talked about *maybe* as a noun, I want to get back to the main question: what is the difference in meaning between the two words?

I think in certain situations, it might be possible to come up with a very slight difference in meaning, but most of the time I think there's too much overlap to claim there's a real distinction.  My intuitive feeling is that *maybe* may express a slightly greater degree of uncertainty in some situations.  (But perhaps not; I've been unable to come up with an example where the words can't be reasonably interchanged.)

Both words are common, but *maybe* appears to be slightly more common.  In both COCA and [GloWbE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/), I find more instances of `maybe` than `perhaps`:

```
   --           COCA        GloWbE
   maybe        125131      413758
   perhaps      97334       387979
```

But oddly, I find the opposite in Google Books Ngram Viewer, which claims there are more than 3 times as many instances of `perhaps`; though when I set it to the fiction sub-corpus, the ratio is closer to 1.  I suppose this supports the idea of the formality difference between the two.

Answer (score -1):

The words are interchangeable, but perhaps is perhaps a bit more formal than maybe.

Comment: A one-liner! Ugh. Should be more like a comment.

Comment: But what if all it takes to answer the question is one line?  :)

Comment: In my opinion, there's nothing wrong with a short answer if there's actually nothing more to say.